# Steam "Corrupt update files" error for Dota 2 since 7.0 update

Tags: 16.04, games, steam

Please excuse me if this is not the correct forum for this, but I can't get a solution anywhere.

Dota 2 Reborn used to run flawlessly on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. Ever since the 7.0 update of Dota 2, whenever an update was downloaded, I got a "corrupt update files" error. I tried reinstalling it - still got the same error. It tries to re-download whenever I try to play the game.

Next, I tried reinstalling Steam. I deleted Dota, completely removed Steam and then reinstalled it. Even now I get the same error on downloading Dota again.

All other Steam games that I have run fine. Dota 2 itself runs perfectly fine on the same machine on Windows 10.

Has anybody had this kind of situation? Any pointer on how to get around this issue would be helpful - I hate depending on Windows for gaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to a difference in filesystem.
My ubuntu uses EXT4, but my Dota is installed on a NTFS partition, and I have that issue. Haven't tried any of the solutions yet. This could interest you:

https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4670

http://steamcommunity.com/app/570/discussions/0/1843493219432308676?ctp=2

Comment: Thanks, that does throw some light on the issue. Seems as though an install in an ext partition might be needed, or at least some symlinking into an ext partition. From all the responses, and my experience, it seems to be a problem with Valve games only.

Answer (score 1):

I think this video might help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWq1qJVJWEM

ROOT access to edit your  /etc/fstab
sudo nano /etc/fstab

and add the line to your HDD mount options.

Here's my example for Arch linux:
template: [UUID or partition] [directory] [type] [mount options] [dump] [pass]

UUID=XXXXXXXXXXX   /run/media/user/drivename    ntfs    defaults,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000     0    0

Answer (score 0):

As @MachinTruc said, the issue was related to fact that Dota was installed on a NTFS partition (while steam was on the root ext4 partition). I installed Dota in a separate ext4 partition and it works fine now.

This seems to be a regression in Dota 2 update 7.0, as other Steam games work fine from the NTFS partition and older versions of Dota 2 worked fine as well.