# Corrupt Update Files on Steam stopping downloads?

Tags: package-management, steam

Whenever I try to download certain games, the install ends unfinished, and if I check the downloads page, it says "Corrupt Update Files". It doesn't happen for every game, but several games are stuck like this, and no amount of verifying the game files, clearing the download cache, or uninstalling and reinstalling completely will help.

I've tried all of the simple steam tricks like clearing the download cache, reinstalling steam, deleting the downloading folder, and nothing worked.

I've tried this but it didn't seem to work, also my main file system is ext4.
[Steam "Corrupt update files" error for Dota 2 since 7.0 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866921/steam-corrupt-update-files-error-for-dota-2-since-7-0-update)

Perhaps something is wrong with my hard drive, as a few weeks ago I was frequently being forced to run a manual fsck on /dev/nvme0n1p2 until that issue stopped suddenly.

Also I've sometimes gotten errors like this while install through terminal:

```
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-470_470.141.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvoptix.so.470.141.03' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvoptix.so.470.141.03.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-470_470.141.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Perhaps unrelated, but Chrome also frequently has sigsegv errors.

I recently installed a brand new ram card, but I'm not sure if that is related.

Thanks for any help.

System Specs:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Hardware model: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG Strix G531GT_G531GT
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12

Here is nvme smart-log output:

```
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0n1p2 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning            : 0
temperature             : 31 C (304 Kelvin)
available_spare             : 100%
available_spare_threshold       : 10%
percentage_used             : 2%
endurance group critical warning summary: 0
data_units_read             : 26,922,963
data_units_written          : 24,306,906
host_read_commands          : 283,177,062
host_write_commands         : 318,279,813
controller_busy_time            : 5,588
power_cycles                : 3,515
power_on_hours              : 7,514
unsafe_shutdowns            : 208
media_errors                : 0
num_err_log_entries         : 0
Warning Temperature Time        : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 6
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 41
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0
```

Comment: Yes, very likely a problem with your NVMe, not "hard", drive.

Comment: I added nvme smart-log info, is there any advice you can give me on how to check for issues?